# Save value with request lifespan in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

Is there a way to store a value that only is valid during the current request in asp.net on the server side. You have the Session where you can set values, you have the Cache where you can set values but you can only read values from the Request. Is there a way to write to the Request or is there other methods to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx). [Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202215202/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx) an example which might help you.